# How to choose days off evenly in a month using python?

Tags: python, algorithm, random

I will assign 8 days off to a crew randomly in a calendar month.

I would like to randomly choose 8 days, and the days off distribution should be as even as possible. I mean all 8 days-off shouldn't be gathered in first 8 days of the month, for example.

For example: [1, 5,  8, 14, 18, 24, 27, 30] is a good distribution.
[1,2,3,4,26,27,28,29] is not a good distribution.

Actually, a crew can't work 7 consecutive days. In every 7 days, there must be 1 day-off.

All days are treated equally, ie Sundays are not days-off by themselves. Crew may work on weekends as well.

I want to choose days-off one by one. Not 8 of them together at once.

Could you recommend an algorithm using python to achieve this?

Not all days in the month may be available to be days off.

Best Regards

Comment: What do you mean by the "distribution should be as even as possible"? You mean something like same number of weekends etc? Or you mean that the density is about the same in the whole month? Or something else?

Comment: @alwbtc What makes one distribution good and another not good?  Can you define some function or some mathematical heuristic that can tell the difference between a good and bad distribution?

Comment: The more evenly distributed the days, the less random your distribution is getting. The two are almost mutually exclusive, so there is a tolerance need to define. How far from perfectly evenly distributed would you allow your dates to be?

Comment: Also, if a crew cannot work for 7 consecutive days, that means *more* than just a day off in every 7 days. If you give a day off on a saturday one week, then the sunday 2 weekends after that, you've given off a day in each of the 7-day periods but there's 12 consecutive working days in there.

Comment: Yes, right, but all days are treated equally in this problem. Sunday is not an off-day by itself. I must add this to my OP!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the key here:

`Actually, a crew can't work 7 consecutive days. In every 7 days, there must be 1 day-off.`

Reword the problem to say a random 2 days in every 7 days (or divide the month into four lengths of time as appropriate).  You are then guaranteed an even-ish distribution.  Use `random.sample()` as Martijn Pieters suggests.

You can generate two values using this technique from the first week, then yield them in sequence if you want them one by one.

**edit:**

As observed by tcaswell, there are still some cases where you end up with ten days in a row on duty.  To combat this, you can assign a day off every three days, create a list of ten, and remove two days at random from the subset of days that don't invalidate the 7-continuous-day criteria.

Alternatively, you could just keep generating lists using the original algorithm until it fits the criteria, since you're very likely to get a valid solution anyway. You'd have to write a validation function of some kind, but it would be very easy to do since you're just counting the longest continuous string of days on.

**CODE:**

An implementation of the second option.

```
import random
from itertools import chain
from itertools import count

def candidate(m):
    ''' Returns 2 days per week, in m days, where m is the length of the month. '''
    weeks = weeksmaker(m)
    return sorted(list(chain(*[random.sample(week, 2) for week in weeks])))

def weeksmaker(m):
    ''' Divides a month up into four weeks, randomly assigning extra days to weeks. '''
    weeks = [range(i, i+7) for i in xrange(1,29,7)]
    for i in range(m - 28):
        weeks[random.randint(1, len(weeks))-1].append(i)
    c = count(1)
    return [[c.next() for day in week] for week in weeks]

def valid(days, c):
    ''' Validity check. Cant work more than c consecutive days. '''
    for i in xrange(1, len(days)):
        if days[i] - days[i-1] > c:
            return False
    else:
        return True

def daysoff(m, n, c):
    ''' In month length m, need n days off, cant work more than c consecutive days. '''
    while True:
        days = candidate(n)
        if valid(days, c):
            return days

>>> for i in range(28, 32):
...     daysoff(i, 8, 7)
... 
[6, 7, 10, 14, 18, 20, 27, 28]
[4, 7, 10, 13, 19, 21, 23, 24]
[2, 4, 9, 13, 15, 20, 25, 27]
[1, 3, 9, 12, 18, 19, 24, 28]
```

Comment: This still falls prey to 'xxooooooooooxx' which gives you 10 days in a row on.

Comment: @tcaswell Fair enough.  Added a potential solution.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) to get a random set from a sequence. List the days that are available, then pass that to the `.sample()` function:

```
import sample
daysoff = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

picked = random.sample(daysoff, 8)
```

In the above example I used the day of the month, and the list omits certain days (say, sundays and the last 10 days of the month), then we pick 8 random days from that population.

Comment: Thanks, but does it guarantee that picked days are evenly distributed? it might choose [1,2,3,4,17,18,19,20] which is not good. Do you know any statistical function such that might use standard deviation etc which will make sure picked days off are evenly selected?

Comment: @alwbtc: Then define *clearly* what you mean by evenly distributed? Random and what I think you mean are not necessarily compatible.

Comment: And I would like to choose days off 1 by one. Each time a day  is picked, it should look at already selected days and do the next selection according to.

Comment: You should really update your question with those details. You are not making it easy for anyone to help you.

Comment: You're right. But generally, problems become clearer as one starts asking the details. I added some more details to my original question.

Comment: Hmm what about 8 consecutive days? Or N consecutive days where N is tolerance?

Comment: At least one day must be off in any 7 consecutive days

Answer (score 1):

You should just split the total number of days.

This code works regardless of the amount of days off needed, and regardless of the days there are in total.

```
from random import randint
def foo(l, n):
    dist = round(len(l)/n)
    return [randint(l[i*dist], l[(i+1)*dist-1]) for i in range(n)]

In [1]: days = [i for i in range(1,31)]
In [2]: foo(days, 8)
Out[2]: [1, 4, 6, 9, 13, 16, 20, 27]

In [3]: mylist = [i for i in range(500)]
In [4]: foo(mylist, 5)
Out[4]: [80, 147, 250, 346, 448]
```

Some problems will occur with the rounding tho, list index might get out of range or so.

Answer (score 1):

This (I think) does what @Martijn did and has the extra benefit of not including consecutive days (eg if you don't want 8 off-days in a row):

```
#Day selector

import random

Ndays = 8
daysoff = range(1,25)
concurrent_tol = 3

while True:
    cntr = 0
    sample = random.sample(daysoff, Ndays)
    sample.sort()
    for i in range(1,Ndays-1):
        if abs(sample[i]-sample[i-1]) == 1:
            cntr +=1
        if abs(sample[i]-sample[i+1]) == 1:
            cntr +=1

    if cntr<concurrent_tol:
        print "Found a good set of off-days :"
        print sample
        break
    else:
        print "Didn't find a good set, trying again"
        print sample
```

Output example:

```
Didn't find a good set, trying again
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11]
Didn't find a good set, trying again
[1, 5, 6, 7, 12, 14, 19, 20]
Didn't find a good set, trying again
[4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 15, 16, 20]
Didn't find a good set, trying again
[3, 4, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14, 23]
Didn't find a good set, trying again
[1, 7, 10, 12, 15, 16, 17, 22]
Didn't find a good set, trying again
[5, 7, 8, 11, 17, 18, 19, 23]
Didn't find a good set, trying again
[3, 8, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 21]
Didn't find a good set, trying again
[2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 21]
Found a good set of off-days :
[1, 2, 5, 12, 15, 17, 19, 20]
```

This also has the added benefit of looking ugly. Note that possible days are 1-24, as defined in daysoff.

Answer (score 0):

Generate (and store) a list of all valid work schedules (via brute force...there are only 30C8 ways to do it).  You can then safely and quickly pick from that list later.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
good_lst = []
for days_off in itertools.combinations(range(30),8):
    if np.max(np.diff( (0,) + days_off + (30,))) < 7:
        good_lst.append(days_off)
```

(there may be some off-by-one bugs in there somplace)

This ran on a decent machine in ~5min.  You will probably want to do more pruning as  (0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 12, 18, 24) is a valid work schedule, but involves 4 sections of 6 work days.